# ext/session concurrency problems example?

Tags: php, session, concurrency

I've always implemented session handling myself using cookies and databases, not through php's ext/session api.

I do it with row locks and the necessary isolation. I never encountered concurrency problems with my method although I don't think I have enough traffic to expose such problems.

I was recently told that ext/session does more than one might expect and that it's more complicated than what I think, which made me question my approach.

Can you provide an example of concurrent requests and the way ext/session solves data inconsistencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With its file-based sessions, `ext/session` implements concurrency protections in the form of a file lock on the opened session. The file lock blocks any other attempt to open the session file, and the lock is not released until the session is closed (either at the end of the request, or explicitly with [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)).

This effectively serializes access to sessions, between that and the entirety of the session being written at once (rather than as separate values), there should not be a problem with inconsistent data.

If you are implementing proper locking and isolation with your custom session implementation, you are doing the same thing `ext/session` is doing, though with a different backing store.

If you want to implement a custom session handler using PHP's `SessionHandlerInterface` and [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php), you would implement this by doing the locking as part of your `open` implementation, and releasing the lock as part of your `close` implementation.

With concurrent requests, the logic flow will look something like this:

```
Connection 1          Connection 2
session open          session open - blocks
session read          //blocked
// do stuff           //blocked
session write         //blocked
session close         //blocked
                      session open returns
                      //reset of session handling as per normal
```

Because `Connection 2` is completely blocked after trying to open the session (and before it receives session data), it can't take any action that might upset the data in the other connection that has access to the session data.

Note that a custom session handler *must* implement locking correctly, or else you can get inconsistent data as a result of multiple concurrent accesses to the session data. What form this inconsistency will take would depend on the exact details of how the custom handler implements reading and writing session data.